# Sonar - guard clause for precondition vs. long conditional block

Tags: sonarqube

Is there a check in Sonar that would identify when preconditions could be checked with a guard clause, rather than wrapping the whole body of the method in an `if` block?

In other words, I would like Sonar to help me find opportunities to refactor something like this

```
 void method(args) {
   if (precondition(args)) {
     // do rest of method
   }
   // no other code after conditional
 }
```

into this:

```
void method(args) {
    if (!precondition(args)) {
      return;
    }
    // do rest of method;
 }
```

This improves readability and reduces nesting depth of conditionals inside the method body proper.

What rule in Sonar would help with this?

Cyclomatic complexity sounds like the *wrong* metric because the early return makes the method score as more complex, while the number of conditionals is the same.  I'm looking for a metric like average nesting depth.